# C programming list node showing last negative element

Tags: c, malloc, nodes

I was having some problem with the linked list. So basically user will just keep enter the values and those values will be added into linked list until user entered -1. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}ListNode;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    ListNode *newNode = NULL, *head = NULL;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    head = newNode;

    printf("Enter a list of numbers, terminated by the value -1: ");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n == -1) {
            newNode->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        else {
            newNode->num = n;
            newNode->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            newNode = newNode->next;
        }
    } while (n != -1);

    newNode = head;
    while (newNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", newNode->num);
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So let's say I entered `1 2 3 4 -1`. The expected output supposed to be `1 2 3 4`. However, I am getting `1 2 3 4 -842150451`. I wonder why is there the -ve number. Is the problem lies with my print listNode part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set the *next* node to NULL if you encounter -1. Its 'current' `num` value is unchanged. You should move creating a new node *before* storing your numbers, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always allocate one more node than numbers entered by the user. That last node's `num` is uninitialized (that's where your garbage value comes from).

Here's a possible fix:

```
ListNode **pnode, *head = NULL;
pnode = &head;

printf("Enter a list of numbers, terminated by the value -1: ");
while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n != -1) {
    *pnode = malloc(sizeof **pnode);
    (*pnode)->num = n;
    (*pnode)->next = NULL;
    pnode = &(*pnode)->next;
}
```

The loop condition makes sure that we were able to read a number, and that the number is not -1.

We only allocate a new node after that (i.e. we allocate only as many nodes as numbers entered).

`pnode` points to the last pointer in the chain of nodes. It marks the spot where the next node should be inserted. Initially this is `&head` (i.e. the first node is stored in `head` (via assignment to `*pnode`)), but it moves along the list with each insert (`pnode = &(*pnode)->next`, the new last pointer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and thanks for the explanation too. Seems like I need more time to brush up my linked list knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The next node allocated in the do/while loop is uninitialized.  Hence the last node has an undetermined `num` field.

Do not use a `do/while` loop.  Check the return value of `scanf`, allocate the node upon need, not in advance.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} ListNode;

int main(void) {
    int n;
    ListNode *head = NULL, **tailp = &head;

    printf("Enter a list of numbers, terminated by the value -1: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n != -1) {
        ListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        newNode->num = n;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        *tailp = newNode;
        tailp = &newNode->next;
    }

    for (ListNode *np = head; np != NULL; np = np->next) {
        printf("%d ", np->num);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two variables called `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your print loop to:

```
while (newNode->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", newNode->num);
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
```

Though this just doesn't print the last redundant node that you are creating. Better would be if you modify your code so that you don't have the redundant node in first place!

Whenever you add a value to a node inside your `else` block by doing `newNode->num = n`, soon after you are creating a new node by doing `newNode->next=malloc(sizeof(ListNode))`. Think about what if it is the last value in your list that you just inserted. Is it really needed to create a new node after that?

Answer (score 0):

You always have one more node in the list than you have values.  That last node's `num` value is unassigned.  What happens if the first value is -1?  You should still have a node in `head`.  Remove the first malloc, and inside the loop, assign `newNode->num` after mallocing.  You'll have to assign `head` there, by checking if it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of 'while' loop while printing based on the condition of whether newNode->next != NULL should resolve your problem.